# ReferenceError: test is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I'm coding a banlist for one of my game servers. I'm using javascript to load the separate PHP page's mysql query, using an ActiveXObject.

```
        function showUser(str) {
      if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
      }
      if (str==0){
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
      }
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      if(!IsNumeric(str)){
          type = "name";
      }
      else
      {
          type = "id";
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?" + type +"="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

That handles the getting of the user's data. I also have a PHP script, on the same page, allowing users to add get requests to the page, to get the user's ban/bans quickly. That is handled by

```
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $name = $_GET['name'];
        if(isset($id)){
            echo '<script> showUser('.$id.') </script>';
        }elseif(isset($name)){
            echo '<script> showUser('. $name .') </script>';
        }
```

My problem comes when I attempt to use the page's name get.

When I browse to my site,

```
http://banlist.unityroleplay.com/minecraft/index.php?name=test
```

I am faced with the error of

> ReferenceError: test is not defined

Any Ideas?

Comment: Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($id)){
            echo '<script> showUser('.$id.') </script>';
        }elseif(isset($name)){
            echo '<script> showUser('. $name .') </script>';
        }
```

this code is trying execute

```
<script>showUser(test)</script>
```

and javascript understanding it as test variable. But you must do it as

```
<script>showUser("test")</script>
```

So, you must change your code as follows:

```
if(isset($id)){
            echo '<script> showUser("'.$id.'") </script>';
        }elseif(isset($name)){
            echo '<script> showUser("'. $name .'") </script>';
        }
```